# Python Pandas concatenate multiple data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am following a [Python for Finance tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/combining-stock-prices-into-one-dataframe-python-programming-for-finance/) where you are combining all the S&P500  stocks into one data frame, i. e. outer joining all the stored CSV files for all the different stocks.

current output:[image: sp500]

The code for this looks like this:

```
def compile_data():
with open("sp500tickers.pickle", "rb") as f:
    tickers = Cpickle.load(f)

main_df = pd.DataFrame()

for count, ticker in enumerate(tickers):
    df = pd.read_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
    df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

    df.rename(columns={'Adj Close': ticker}, inplace=True)
    df.drop(['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'], 1, inplace=True)

    if main_df.empty:
        main_df = df
    else:
        main_df = main_df.join(df, how='outer')


    if count % 10 == 0:
        print(count)
print(main_df.head())
main_df.to_csv('sp500_joined_closes.csv')

compile_data()
```

Ideally I would like the data frames to be joined/concatenated like this:
[image: Desired output]

All ideas and tips are greatly appreciated.

Best regards,
Rubrix

Comment: Do you know how to use `pivot` in Pandas?

Comment: You can use the df.transpose() method.

Comment: Not sure how to use pivot in pandas thats why i transformed it in excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `melt` like:

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Date'], var_name='Ticker', value_name='Closed')
```

Comment: So would it be like this then ?
        main_df = main_df.melt(df, id_vars='Date', var_name='Ticker', value_name='Closed')

instead of:
 main_df = main_df.join(df, how='outer')

Comment: TypeError: melt() got multiple values for argument 'id_vars'

Comment: The new code: https://codeshare.io/amDv7o
Gives me this error:
  new = arr[tuple(slobj)]
MemoryError